# Css content Image not showing up on Firefox

Tags: html, css, safari, overlay

I have the following css that displays a small graphic on top of another graphic, and it works well on every browser except Firefox. On Firefox a small yellow box appears, but no image.  Is there anything I can do to make it appear on Firefox too?

```
.post-content-contract {
background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) none repeat scroll 0 0;
opacity: 1;
top:5%;
left:5%;
max-width: 50%;
max-height: 50%; 
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff; 
content:url(contract.png);
}
```

Comment: can you make this into a full working snippet?

Comment: snippet available at https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/R5Bbr

Comment: I already looked on your website. My answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content` [is not meant to be used this way](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp). It's use is limited to `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

In your case, the best option is to use `background-image` instead:

```
.post-content-contract {
    background-image: url(contract.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, my solution is the proper way of doing this. You need to understand that browsers often fix incorrect behavior or expect it. It doesn't mean that you should keep writing improper markup. On the flip side, another option you have is to convert `.post-content-contract` into a pseudo element.

Comment: my apologies Serg, I wrote that comment before actually trying it, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @BillTeale no worries, glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, Firefox doesn't support the `content` rule for `img` tag. In my case replacing `img` with `div` did the trick (`img` was used only as a "container", as all the attribute and the content was specified in css) and the image was shown on Chrome and Firefox. **It doesn't work on IE or Edge though**.

Answer (score 4):

for me i found that setting it as an img in my html was the problem.  changing from "img" tag to "span" tag was the trick for me to make it work on FireFox.